# Postgresql 14 - comit in procedure raises error

Tags: postgresql-14

What I've read, it should be possible in Postgresql 14 to add commit in a procedure, but in my case it raises an error.
For testing it, I wrote following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.committest()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
  test bigint;
    BEGIN
        select id into test from "AUTH".info;
        commit;
    END;
$procedure$
;
```

Then execute with

```
call public.committest();
```

The error message is:

```
SQL-Fehler [2D000]: ERROR: invalid transaction termination
  Wobei: PL/pgSQL function committest() line 6 at COMMIT
```

But it's only on the (ubuntu) server. On my local development environment, it is working. So I think, I need to configure something? But I can't find out what I need to configure.

Comment: The caller probably already started a transaction.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I did the call in psql and dbeaver directly after starting them. And also an application which is calling the functions (and didn't start transactions) get this error.